# Issue with deploying maven

Tags: java, maven

I have the following POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.eternity</groupId>
<artifactId>Eternity</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <!-- Common build properties -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <!-- Artifacts versioning properties -->
    <lombok.version>1.16.6</lombok.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
    <swagger-mvc.version>2.0.1</swagger-mvc.version>
    <jackson-datatype.version>2.6.4</jackson-datatype.version>
    <guava.version>19.0</guava.version>
    <commons.lang3.version>3.4</commons.lang3.version>
    <querydsl.version>3.7.1</querydsl.version>

</properties>

<distributionManagement>

</distributionManagement>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Common dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-mvc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-datatype.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-datatype.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistence dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Common dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Persistence dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache POI dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<profiles>

    <!-- Default Portal application maven profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And when I am trying to deploy, I get the following error:

```
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 20.148s [INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 07 17:45:33
> CEST 2016 [INFO] Final Memory: 55M/516M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy
> (default-deploy) on project Eternity: Deployment failed: repository
> element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement
> element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter ->
> [Help 1]
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Answer is in the error message: "repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) of deploy plugin. You need to specify a remote repository under the distribution management section of your pom. This will tell maven where your artifact needs to be deployed:

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>internal.repo</id>
      <name>MyCo Internal Repository</name>
      <url>Host to Company Repository</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your error log you have:
`> element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement`

You have to specify something within your `<distributionManagement>` tag. Since you left it empty, you're getting the error. If you need to know what you need to include within the tag, then you may want to read about it on the [Maven Reference Here](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management).